# Why js-lint task is giving undefined on every file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jslint

I am building a gulp file, which is this one

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var jslint = require('gulp-jslint');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('public/stylesheets/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'));
});

gulp.task('jslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['public/*/*'])
            .pipe(jslint({ /* this object represents the JSLint directives being passed down */ }))
            .pipe(jslint.reporter( 'default' ));
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
      server: "./public"
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    var reload = browserSync.reload;
    gulp.watch("public/stylesheets/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("*.js").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("public/*.html").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("public/*.js").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("public/*/*.js").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("public/*/*.css").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("public/*/*.scss").on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'serve', 'watch', 'jslint']);
```

in the jslint task, I am getting this

[image]

and I am wondering why?

here is the sort of my folders:

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: @The yes, already tried that

Comment: I'm getting the same thing! Any progress on this?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error.  Please let us know if there is any progress.